# messages not kept in sent folder in mu4e emacs

Tags: emacs, smtp, mu4e

I have mu4e smtp setup with the default mu4e mail sending function.
I tried nullmailer but I didn't manage to configure it to work from mu4e.
I was following [this](https://vxlabs.com/2014/06/06/configuring-emacs-mu4e-with-nullmailer-offlineimap-and-multiple-identities/) tutorial for nailmailer, and [this one](http://cachestocaches.com/2017/3/complete-guide-email-emacs-using-mu-and-/) for the default setup.

I was trying with and without a code that's recommended for gmail (my account is not gmail) because of the way gmail saves the sent items , in order to avoid duplicates (see [here](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Sending-mail.html#Sending-mail) for mu4e user manual):

```
;; don't save messages to Sent Messages, Gmail/IMAP takes care of this
(setq mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
```

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that the sent emails are not saved to the sent folder, not locally and not on the server.

my init file looks like this:

```
(setq mu4e-sent-folder "/sent"
      mu4e-drafts-folder "/drafts"
      message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      user-mail-address "MY.EMAIL.ADDRESS"
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "MY.SMTP.SERVER"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "MY.SMTP.SERVER"
      smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it ..

```
(require 'smtpmail)
```

was missing from my init file.
No wonder there was little interest in my question...

Comment: if this solves your problem. accept it as an answer.